# Hover in and Hover out menù

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a small problem. i'm trying to develop a simple menu with jquery, the model based my menù is [here](http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_41878/index.html#!/page_about).
I tried to develop it, I can play the animation of all elements at the same time but only one at a time and I can not.
The following is my code html and js:

**JS**

```
$('.menu').hover(
        function () {
            $(".mText",this).stop(true).animate({ top: '70px' }, 400, 'easeOutCubic');
            $(".mText_over",this).stop(true).animate({ top: '0px' }, 500, 'easeOutCubic');
        },
        function () {
            if ((!$('li').hasClass('with_ul')) || (!$('li').hasClass('sfHover'))) {
                $(".mText").stop(true).animate({ top: '0px' }, 400, 'easeInOutCubic');
                $(".mText_over").stop(true).animate({ top: '-70px' }, 400, 'easeInOutCubic');
            }
        }
    );
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="menuHolder">
<nav id="menuV" class="menu">
    <ul id="menu" class="sf-js-enabled">
        <li><a href="#!/page_about">
            <div
            class="mText" style="top: 0px;">
                About Us
            </div>
            <div class="mText_over" style="top: -70px;">
                About 

                Us
            </div>
            </a></li>
        <li class="with_ul"><a
            href="#!/page_portfolio1">
            <div class="mText" style="top: 0px;">Portfolio</div>
            <div class="_arrPl" style="top: 20px;">
            </div>
            <div class="mText_over" style="top: -50px;">Portfolio</div>
            </a>
            <ul class="submenu_1" style="top: 41px; visibility: visible; display: none;">
                <li><a
                    href="#!/page_more">Laystras</a></li>
                <li><a
                    href="#!/page_more">Mausya</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!/page_more"
                    class="last">Leryse</a>
                    <ul
                    class="submenu_2" style="top: 41px;">
                        <li><a href="#!/page_more">aksase</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#!/page_more" class="last">masaysa</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#!/page_services">
            <div
            class="mText" style="top: 0px;">
                Services
            </div>
            <div class="mText_over" style="top: -70px;">
                Services
            </div>
            </a></li>
        <li><a href="#!/page_tutorials">
            <div
            class="mText" style="top: 0px;">
                Tutorials
            </div>
            <div class="mText_over" style="top: -70px;">
                Tutorials
            </div>
            </a></li>
        <li class="no_bg"><a href="#!/page_mail">
            <div
            class="mText" style="top: 0px;">
                Contacts
            </div>
            <div class="mText_over" style="top: -70px;">
                Contacts
            </div>
            </a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Where is there a problem on your site? Please make it clear...

Comment: The site link is an example found on the net as I would like to develop the menu that I would like. My problem is that I can not animate only a single element but all the elements simultaneously.

Comment: Can you make a small JSFiddle to show your problem?

Comment: I'm trying but I can not run the findle, this is frustrating... [link](http://jsfiddle.net/silentgrave/4pSEC/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you might want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rVpTe/1/).

```
.sf-js-enabled {
    height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
   /*  background: gray; */
}

.sf-js-enabled li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    /* background: silver; */

}

.sf-js-enabled li > a {
    position: relative;
    top    : -20px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sf-js-enabled li:hover > a {
    top: 0;   
}
```

Comment: Is just that. But at this point it's no use javascript code, since it takes advantage of CSS?

Comment: The transition is pure CSS, sorry. I updated the fiddle.